# Drop Observable subscription when Subject has 0 observers

Tags: rxjs

I want to have a cold multicast Observable. My source Observable passes the values to a ReplaySubject(1), to whom multiple observers can subscribe, and the underlying subscription drops when there's no observer. In clear, I want:

```
const m = source.pipe(shareReplay(1), refCount());
```

But with one important difference: I want all observers to subscribe to a Subject instead of the `m` above. (Because I want to be able to call `subject.next()` too).

```
import { interval, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

const source = interval(1000);
const subject = new ReplaySubject(1);

const m = source.pipe(
  multicast(() => subject),
  refCount()
);

subject.subscribe(...); // Not working, cold source not firing.
m.subscribe(...); // Works, but not what I want.
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Edit:

For clarification, I am going to rephrase.

Let me define `m` as

```
const m = source.pipe(shareReplay(1), refCount());
```

`m` is cold, so when the first `m.subscribe()` is called, the interval `interval(1000)` will start running, until no more observers are subscribed to `m`. This is `refCount`'s behavior.

I want to have the same behavior, with one difference: Instead of subscribing to the Observable `m`, I want all observers to subscribe to a Subject. I.e.:

```
const source = interval(1000);
const mySubject = new ReplaySubject(1);

/* Do some magic with source and mySubject */

const subscription = mySubject.subscribe(...); // Will start the interval(1000)
// Wait a couple of seconds
subscription.unsubscribe(); // Will stop the interval
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do to be honest

Comment: Added clarifications. Hope that helps.

Comment: So you want the subscribers to receive 1 event every second, + 1 event every time you decide to emit one using next(), is that right? If so, just merge the interval observable with a Subject , and use shareReplay(1) on this merged observable.

Comment: @JBNizet Correct, but I want subscribers also to subscribe directly to the same Subject they're calling next() on. In your case, they'd subscribe to the `merge()` and call next on another Subject.

Comment: I think what you're asking for goes against the principle of observables: sources emit events, and are transformed by operators to create another observable, that you subscribe to. So the source of the events, used to emit, and the observable to which you subscribe should be two connected, but different objects.

Comment: I get your point, but they apply for Observables. For me, Subject were created to handle the cases where you want to have one single object handling the 2 sides of the tunnel. Hence the `subscribe()` and `next()` methods present on this object.

Comment: I still don't think that's the best design, but I guess this is what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcpmuj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @JBNizet This is close to what I want, but not exactly. With this setup, the source `i` becomes hot. Try commenting line 21 in your code, and you'll see the `events2` array starts at 4. I want it to start at 0.